# Hive how to get second max, less than max not working

Tags: hive

I searched stackoverflow and found this solution in SQL

```
select max(concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day)) from db.table where concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day) < (select max(concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day)) from db.tale)
```

However, this is not working in hive, with the error -

```
UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: scalar-subquery#118829
```

How can I accomplish this task in hive? (Attempting to get second max)

Answer (score 0):

You have ranking functions to do this.

```
select * 
from (select row_number() over(order by concat(snapshot_year_month,snapshot_day) desc) as rnum 
      from db.table
     ) t 
where rnum=2
```

This assumes the concatenated column is unique. If not unique, use `dense_rank`.